# Binary arithmatic with sign magnitde representation

Tags: arithmetic, binary

Consider the arithmetic operations with sign magnitude representation. Assume we want to calculate `BA + 13` and the base is Hex. What is the result?!

We know that that the MSB bit is the sign bit. So we are performing

```
   1101 1010  
+  0001 0011
 -------------
```

That means the first number is negative and the second one is positive. How do we determine the sign? Other bits are pretty simple:

```
   X100 0111
```

Comment: Which input has the larger magnitude, the positive or the negative one? The result of the addition has the same sign as the input with larger magnitude.

Comment: Who should find that? Assume these numbers are given to a computer with sign-magnitude representation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the addition of two $8$ bit numbers with sign-magnitude representation

First separate the sign bits `1` and `0`.  These are different, so the underlying calculation is a subtraction rather than an addition.

The larger unsigned $7$ bit number is `101 1010` associated with the sign `1`, while the smaller unsigned $7$ bit number is `001 0011` associated with the sign `0`, so the sign of the result is that of the larger unsigned $7$ bit number (`1` here) and the unsigned $7$ bit calculation subtracts the smaller from the larger

```
   101 1010  
-  001 0011
 -------------
   100 0111
```

making the final result `1100 0111` which would correspond to hexadecimal `C7` (assuming the original question in fact started with `DA` and `13`)

As a comment, using two's complement would be easier for addition and subtraction of negative numbers, and there is an easy translation between sign-magnitude representation and two's complement via one's complement.